# How to use IN & NOT IN same query

Tags: mysql

I have a query which consists of both `IN` & `NOT` in the query but it gives me an error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN ('aniket27') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2' at line 1

This is how my query looks

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE username IN ('aniket27','deepakrajak','bhawana','Mehul13','sanchayeeta',
                   'shivajidutta', 'anamika_4a','parekh','anupamkumar') 
AND NOT IN ('aniket27') 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: `AND username NOT IN()`. But your conditions actually do not make sense: `username IN('aniket27', ...) 
AND NOT IN ('aniket27')`???

Comment: Yeah, unless the column you're referring to in your `NOT IN` is not username, you're trying to include it and exclude it, which seems a little odd.

Comment: Yes, better do this excluding the "aniket27" in the first place (in php code likely).

Comment: Is there PHP/mysqli usage to this question? Seems like just SQL/mysql issue..

Comment: @chris85 actually yes, see my comment.

Comment: @smozgur, not seeing PHP/mysqli in the question.. That is only a SQL query.

Comment: @chris85 yes, I agree but the solution could be with php easily. that's what I meant. I can see that OP is using an array in the script (likely php since there was a php tag before - which I believe helps to solve it) and excluding item should be also defined/collected in the script, so it could be better excluded before creating the query. of course only my idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to put the field name before "NOT IN" :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IN ('aniket27','deepakrajak','bhawana','Mehul13','sanchayeeta','shivajidutta','anamika_4a','parekh','anupamkumar') AND username NOT IN ('aniket27') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You must specify column for `NOT IN`

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username IN ('...') AND username NOT IN ('aniket27') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2
```

But first condition will be sufficient to match elements that are listed in `NOT IN` part, just remove them from first `IN` list.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE username IN ('aniket27','deepakrajak','bhawana','Mehul13','sanchayeeta','shivajidutta','anamika_4a','parekh','anupamkumar') 
AND username NOT IN ('aniket27') 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2;
```